# Batch file to move files to directories in round-robin fashion

Tags: batch, script

I am trying to have a batch file that moves ".doc" files to a folder. The trick is that i have three user folders named Mark, Luke and John that I want these files to go to. Example, aa.doc is in a folder and it moves it to marks folder. Then when the next files aa1.doc comes in it moves it to luke's folder. Next file moves to John folder and this process repeats giving out files evenlly amongst the three user folders

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Will the round robin tracking need to persist between runs?  Or can the round robin begin again with mark?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
SET "target0=Marcella"
SET "target1=Lucca"
SET "target2=Daniella"

FOR %%A IN (*.doc) DO (
    SET /a counter+=1
    SET /a pointer=counter%%3
    SET "file=%%~A"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    CALL SET "target=%%target!pointer!%%"
    ECHO MOVE "!file!" "!target!"
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

Comment: ECHO MOVE "!file!" is this were I put in the file directory?

Comment: `Marcella`, `Lucca` and `Daniella` are the target subfolders. You may set the source folder by a `cd` command: `cd /d X:\Users\Me\Doc Files`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@echo off
Rem allow for reusable variables
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELATEDEXPANSION

Set mark=0
Set luke=1
Set david=2

Rem drawing from your example
set prefix=aa

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b *.doc`) do (
        Rem strips file extension

        set file=%%~ni 

        setfilename=%%i

        Rem extracts numeric substring

        set num=%file:%~prefix%=%

        )

       Rem Divide num by 3 and return remainder

       set mod=(%num%) % 3
       if %mod%==%mark% (move %filename% Mark)
       if %mod%==%luke% (move %filename% Luke) else (move %filename% David)

endlocal
exit /b
```

This may require tweaking for your exact needs, but this will put you on track.